# Bring app to front from foreground service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have an app that enables people to send alarms to groups of other users and I have implemented support to trigger alarms from a BLE device. It all works as expected, except for when the app is in background.

I use a foreground service to listen for the device event and a local broadcast to trigger the actual alarm. The alarm get triggered as expected and all code runs (sending alarm to server, playing audio, etc) but the app stays in background.

I have tried several solutions but failed to come up with a working one. Either the answers are too old or they just do not work (as in unwanted results).

I want the exact same result as when tapping the foreground notification = resume the current activity without passing destroy.

I'm actually surprised how hard this seems to be, in my opinion it should be easy as "bringToFront()" since the activity is obviously running.

Any help would be much appreciated!

I don't think any of my code would help to understand my problem, but here's some anyways:

***AlarmDeviceService.java*** - The service listening for BLE events:

```
private void sendAlarmTriggerBroadcastMessage(String deviceName){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(ALARM_DEVICE_TRIGGERED);
        intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_SOURCE_NAME, deviceName);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

***AlarmDeviceBroadcastReceiver.java:***

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, "Received: "+ action);
        if(mReceiver != null){
            if(action.equals(AlarmDeviceService.ALARM_DEVICE_TRIGGERED)) {
                mReceiver.onDeviceAlarmBroadcast();
            }
            else if(action.equals(AlarmDeviceService.ALARM_DEVICE_CONNECTED)){
                String mac = intent.getStringExtra(AlarmDeviceService.INTENT_EXTRA_SOURCE_MAC);
                mReceiver.onAlarmDeviceConnected(mac);
            }
            else if(action.equals(AlarmDeviceService.ALL_DEVICES_CONNECTED)){
                mReceiver.onAllDevicesConnected();
            }
        }
    }
```

***AlarmActivity.kt*** - The activity that should be brought to front:

```
    override fun onDeviceAlarmBroadcast(){
        if (alarmUtilities?.alarmSentHandler?.currentSentAlarm == null) {
            Log.d(LOG, "Doing it!")
            triggerDefaultAlarm()
        }else{
            alarmUtilities?.alarmSentHandler?.cancelAlarm()
        }
    }
```

If my question is poorly put, please excuse me - it's my first post.